# Continue developing live windows azure + entity framework code first side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I've worked on ASP.NET MVC site using Entity Framework code first approach.
I've finished my initial website and uploaded it to Windows Azure.

Now, I wish to continue developing the site and enhance the database structure.
The problem is that because it was created as code-first when I'll modify my entities - the database will re-created so my data will be lost.

My questions is - how can I get the live data from windows azure back to my local machine (registered accounts, posts etc.) and how can I continue developing my site without loosing that data. To be more specific - I wish to update the database structure in Azure to the new structure without losing the data inside it. I know about the entity framework DB strategics, but didn't saw anything that saves the data.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: From version 4.3 Entity Framework includes Migrations. That way you can keep your existing data. Please visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx for more info about it...

Comment: @rjovic Thanks! Can you post this as answer so I can mark it as the correct answer? The only thing I've changed is to use Automatic Migration, but the site you've post got an article about it too! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are instructions for exporting form SQL Azure to blob storage. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh335292.aspx#Export

As rjovic said modifying your entities doesn't imply losing data. You can used code first [migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx) move data from your old entities to your new ones.